# keypad not working for textfield in uiactionsheet

Tags: uitextfield, uiactionsheet

i have added textfeld in uiactionsheet as

```
-(void)showAction {
 printf("getting action ready \n");
 UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Sheet Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
       [asheet showInView:self.view];  
       [asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320,200)];
       UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100,200, 25)];
 textField.borderStyle= UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
 [textField becomeFirstResponder];
 [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet];
 [textField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
 textField.text=@"test" ;
 textField.delegate=self;
 [asheet insertSubview:textField atIndex:0];
 [textField release];
 [asheet release];
}
```

but keypad is not working for this textfield however backspace is working.
previously when i have been using ios 3 its workd fine but with ios 3.2 iphone simulator 4.0 does not accept any input from keypad

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 printf("\n textFieldShouldBeginEditing\n ");
 return YES;
}
```

this gets called

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 printf("shouldChangeCharactersInRange  %s ",[string UTF8String]);
 return YES;
}
```

however this delegate method gets called only for backspace.

Answer (score 9):

Just use this way it works for me

First set the the UITextFieldDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate in your class .h file

#define TEXT_FIELD_TAG      9999

#define ACTION_SHEET_TAG    8888

```
-(IBAction)ForgotPassword:(id)sender{


     UIActionsheet  *actFollowUp = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Enter Email"
                                                      delegate:self
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                      destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

actFollowUp.tag=ACTION_SHEET_TAG;

textFieldTime = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.f,320.f, 200.f, 30.f)];
[textFieldTime setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
textFieldTime.delegate= self;
[textFieldTime setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet];
textFieldTime.keyboardAppearance= UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textFieldTime.tag=TEXT_FIELD_TAG;

[actFollowUp addSubview:textFieldTime];

UIWindow*   appWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

[actFollowUp showInView:appWindow];
[actFollowUp setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,200.0, 320.0, 200.0)];

[self performSelector: @selector(acceptInput:) withObject: actFollowUp];
```

}

```
 -(void)acceptInput: (UIActionSheet*)actionSheet
{

 UITextField*    textField = (UITextField*)[actionSheet viewWithTag:TEXT_FIELD_TAG];

UIWindow*       appWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

CGRect          frame     = textField.frame;

[appWindow insertSubview:textField aboveSubview:actionSheet];

frame.origin.y += 60.0; // move text field to same position as on action sheet

textField.frame = frame;

}
```