# Textview in the UIActionSheet not accept any characters in ios6

Tags: ios, uitextview, uiactionsheet, uiwindow

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367494/keypad-not-working-for-textfield-in-uiactionsheet) I refer this link and some other link. I have a view which contains textview. First I present **actionsheet** with size window size in navigationcontroller.view. After I add my view like below.

```
[[[actionSheet subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
 UIWindow *appWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
 [appWindow insertSubview:successView aboveSubview:contactActionSheet];
```

It works fine in Ios7 but in IOS 6 my view display below in actionSheet. So I add my view as subview in action sheet. Space, return and delete works in textview but not accept any character at first attempt(That is if textview become firstResponder in second time it accept all the character).

Please help me to solve this problem. I spend lot of time in that but still I cant find any solution.